# How to add animate css to bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add to my dropdown one of the classes of ***animate css with bootstrap 3 dropdown native events*** but it doesn't work. Could you help me with this problem.

Thank you very much.

Here is the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
            $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').addClass('fadeInLeft');
          })
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine both by adding it in the markup or via js as you have.  What is not working for you?  http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/6j3pwg6x/2/

Comment: Thank you for your markup example. I don't know how it is working on jsfiddle but on my computer it worked after adding animated class.
Here is what I mean.
$('.dropdown:eq(1)').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
   $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').addClass('fadeInLeft animated');
  });

Comment: Okay, I'm glad that the markup example worked.  Just note that I used :eq(1) in the selector for the jQuery example so that it would only apply to the second dropdown.  Your original code was correct and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script inside a script element and update to this, using jQuery's native `fadeIn`:

```
<script>
  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
      $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn(500);
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
      $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut(500);
  });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebovbyv5/1/